# Подскажите хорошие книги по Action Script?

Tags: flash, книги, actionscript

Хотелось бы что-то среднее - не для новичков, т.к. прогой занимаюсь не первый год, но и не для профи, т.к. во флэше не работал ни разу.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Actionscript 3.0](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948/)

Update:

Ну и [Programming Flex 3](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516215/) заодно

Answer (score 1):

ActionScript 3.0 для Flash. Подробное руководство. Колин Мук. Согласен со всеми 5-здездными отзывами на Озоне: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4121608/#comments
В интернете тоже валяется.